# Comparing two passwords for validation in C++

Tags: c++, function, validation, do-while

I am trying to compare two C++ strings. This function passes an old password to be compared with to a new password. The condition for this new password is that the first half of the new password and old password cannot be the same and the second half of the new password and old password cannot be the same. For example, if the old password was ABCDEFGH and the new password was ABCDyzyz, the new password will not be accepted since the first half of these passwords are the same. I have come up with this so far and it runs but the display doesn't show the output statement. Am I comparing them correctly?

```
bool changePassword(string& password)
{
string newPW;
int lengthnewPW;
int lengtholdPW;
float sizeN;
float half;

do
{
    cout << "Enter new password: ";
    getline(cin, newPW);



    lengthnewPW = newPW.length();
    lengtholdPW = password.length();
    if (lengthnewPW < lengtholdPW)
    {
        sizeN = lengthnewPW;
    }
    else if (lengtholdPW < lengthnewPW)
    {
        sizeN = lengtholdPW;
    }
    else
        sizeN = lengtholdPW;


    half = sizeN / 2;


   if (newPW.compare(0, half - 1, password) == 0 || newPW.compare(half, (sizeN - half) - 1, password) == 0)
   {
       cout << "The new password cannot start or end with " << half << " or more characters that are the same as the old password" << endl << endl;
   }


} while (newPW.compare(0, half - 1, password) == 0 || newPW.compare(half, (sizeN - half) - 1, password) == 0 );

return true;
}
```

Comment: Use ==>  size_t half = std::min< size_t >( newPW.length(), password.length() ) >> 1;
Keep in mind, that you could have half = 0 such that half - 1 < 0

Comment: If this is not homework, [read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).  Otherwise, please kindly let your instructor know that the rest of the world would appreciate it if he/she spent a little time thinking of more creative/engaging/practical homework problems.  This is the kind of thing that turns potential future developers into humanities majors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
bool changePassword(const string& password)
{
    for( ; ; )
    {
        string newPW;
        cout << "Enter new password: ";
        getline( cin, newPW );

        size_t half = ( newPW.length() < password.length() ? newPW.length() : password.length() ) >> 1;
        // May want to to add: if( !newPW.empty() )
        if( ( password.size() <= 2 ) ||
            ( ( password.substr( 0, half ) != newPW.substr( 0, half ) ) &&
              ( password.substr( password.size() - half ) != newPW.substr( newPW.size() - half ) ) ) )
            return true;  // <-- Will you ever return non-true?  Max retries?

        cout << "The new password cannot start or end with " << half << " or more characters that are the same as the old password" << endl << endl;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This isn't checking the second half of the password.  Also it will reject all 1-2 character original passwords, even though the OP never mentioned anything about that.

Comment: `x >> 1` for halving `x`. Don't do that. It's not the 90's anymore.

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis this is for an assignment, and I'm not allowed to use the STL library. Is there another way to use `size_t half = std::min< size_t >( newPW.length(), password.length() ) >> 1;`

Comment: size_t half = ( newPW.length() < password.length() ? newPW.length() : password.length() ) >> 2;

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis `cout << "The new password cannot start or end with " << half << " or more characters that are the same as the old password" << endl << endl;` Thank you for your help, but the half being displayed here always shows the number 2 when it runs. Using an 8 character password still shows up as 2 for the half. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Mark use the code above rather than my comment afterwards.

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis It works thank you! I have one more question. How would I continue to keep looping to ask the user to enter a new password until it passes the condition of not having the same first half or second half as the old password? I'm trying to put your code into a do while loop so that it can keep repeating to ask for a new password.

Comment: for(;;) is an infinite loop.  So if it does not pass the test (fails the if statement) it will prompt the error at the end of the loop and repeat from the top of the loop.